# SVD of a matrix

Tags: svd

Can someone please tell me the Singular Value Decomposition of A= $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix} $.
I calculated U= $$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
\frac{-1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
\end{bmatrix} $$
and the eigenvalues came out to be 0,2. Now I am facing problem with finding V.
Can somebody please help me in finding the v1, v2 for V ?

Comment: was my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution of $A=UDV$ is
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}0&0\\0&\sqrt{2}\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{matrix}\right)\,.
$$